# Sync via USB on AnkiDroid 2.3.1?

Tags: sync, amazon-kindle-fire, ankidroid

The old AnkiDroid for Kindle Fire had an option to sync via AnkiDroid which imported decks from AnkiDesktop (super fast and used less data).  The thing is, I can only download about 2 gigs of data per month before my internet speed drops to 14.4kbps (which is like no Internet, honestly).  So, is this still possible in AnkiDriod 2.3.1?  If so, where is it?  And can't I interrupt the sync that's happening now without corrupting anything?  Because it's already 120 mb deep.

Comment: I actually can't tell if the sync is coming from the web or from the USB connection, but I felt the 2.0.1 version was much faster.

Comment: Now, exporting my decks with media and importing them to my device takes over an hour.  So, why was the old version of AnkiDroid so much faster at syncing?